# Convert gzipped data fetched by urllib2 to HTML

Tags: python, gzip, urllib2

I currently use mechanize to read gzipped web page as below:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
response = br.open(url)
data = response.read()
```

I wonder how to decompress gzipped data fetched by urllib2 to HTML text?

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
response = opener.open(req)
data = response.read()
if response.info()['content-encoding'] == 'gzip':
    HOW TO DECOMPRESS DATA TO HTML
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
import StringIO
data = StringIO.StringIO(data)
import gzip
gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=data)
html = gzipper.read()
```

`html` should now hold the HTML (*Print it to see*). See [here](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/diveintopython/html/http_web_services/gzip_compression.html) for more info.

Comment: You can also just do `gzip.decompress(data)`.

Comment: This is not actually working in this case as explained in this article: http://rationalpie.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/python-streaming-gzip-decompression/ so you have to use zlib instead of gzip

Comment: @gabuzo Actually, that article concerns _streaming_ gzip decompression, which is indeed very different from the topic of this question, since this one specifically mentions that the data was already fetched, whereas in a streaming situation you want to decompress as you're receiving it.

Answer (score -2):

```
def ungzip(r,b):
    headers = r.info()
    if ('Content-Encoding' in headers.keys() and headers['Content-Encoding']=='gzip') or \
       ('content-encoding' in headers.keys() and headers['content-encoding']=='gzip'):
        import gzip
        gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=r, mode='rb')
        html = gz.read()
        gz.close()
        headers['Content-type'] = 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
        r.set_data(html)
        b.set_response(r)
```