# Why I got messy characters while opening url using urllib2?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

Here's my code, you guys can also test it out. I always get messed-up characters instead of page source.

```
Header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8 GTB7.1 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"}

Req = urllib2.Request("http://rlslog.net", None, Header)

Response = urllib2.urlopen(Req)

Html = Response.read()

print Html[:1000]
```

Normally `Html` should be page source, but it ended up to be tons of messed-up characters. Anybody knows why?

BTW: I'm on python 2.7

Comment: Works fine for me, the problem must be somewhere else. Maybe some simple mistake in the way you output the response?

Comment: @kapep: Are you sure? I just simply 'print Html[:100]', they are all messed up. What python version are you on?

Comment: It was just a wild guess since the print part was not included. Works as expected for me. Using 2.6.4.

Comment: @kapep: Now just out of nowhere, everything works fine! Same code, nothing changed. Oh man, I'm confused...

Comment: @Shane: "nothing changed": on your side not, but maybe something changed on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bruce already suggested, it seems to be a problem with compression. The server returns gzip compressed content, but `urllib2` does not support automatic gzip compression. In fact, the server is misbehaving in this case as far as I know: it should only compress the content if an `Accept-encoding: gzip` header is present (which you either provide yourself, or is automatically added by your client if it supports it).

So: either use a library that supports it automatically, like [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) (which I've tested with the page in question, and it works), or decompress yourself (see the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704754/convert-gzipped-data-fetched-by-urllib2-to-html) for how to do it, note that in the question the headers returned by the server are checked to see if the content is gzip compressed)

Answer (score 0):

You make your request with a user agent which supports on the fly compression. Are you sure that the output is not gzip compressed ? Try running it through [zlib module](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html) and/or printing headers