# python urllib2.urlopen - html text is garbled - why?

Tags: python, html, urllib2, mechanize-python

The printed html returns garbled text... instead of what I expect to see as seen in "view source" in browser.

Why is that? How to fix it easily?

Thank you for your help.

Same behavior using mechanize, curl, etc.

```
import urllib
import urllib2



start_url = "http://www.ncert.nic.in/ncerts/textbook/textbook.htm"
response = urllib2.urlopen(start_url)
html = response.read()
print html
```

Comment: I am not able to replicate this. What does "garbled" mean, in your context? I am getting html exactly as I'd expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same garbled text using curl

```
curl http://www.ncert.nic.in/ncerts/textbook/textbook.htm
```

The result appears to be gzipped. So this shows the correct HTML for me.

```
curl http://www.ncert.nic.in/ncerts/textbook/textbook.htm | gunzip
```

Here's a solutions on doing this in Python: [Convert gzipped data fetched by urllib2 to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704754/convert-gzipped-data-fetched-by-urllib2-to-html)

Edited by OP:

The revised answer after reading above is:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import gzip
import StringIO

start_url = "http://www.ncert.nic.in/ncerts/textbook/textbook.htm"
response = urllib2.urlopen(start_url)
html = response.read()

data = StringIO.StringIO(html)
gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=data)
html = gzipper.read()
```

`html` now holds the HTML (Print it to see)

Comment: Perhaps check for the existence of the 'Content-Encoding: gzip' header before gzippin'.

Answer (score 3):

Try requests. [Python Requests.](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

```
import requests
response = requests.get("http://www.ncert.nic.in/ncerts/textbook/textbook.htm")
print response.text
```

The reason for this is because the site uses gzip encoding. To my knowledge urllib doesn't support deflating so you end up with compressed html responses for certain sites that use that encoding. You can confirm this by printing the content headers from the response like so.

```
print response.headers
```

There you will see that the "Content-Encoding" is gzip format. In order to get around this using the standard urllib library you'd need to use the gzip module. Mechanize also does this because it uses the same urllib library. Requests will handle this encoding and format it nicely for you.

Comment: hi i didn't about requests before... so is this better than using urllib2.. and can I completely use requests in the future in place of urllib2 and expect everything to work and better.

Comment: Whether or not the library is "better" than requests is open to interpretation. I tend to like it quite a bit and haven't had any problems using it so far. It's based off of the urllib2 library so most of your operations should also work with this library.