# Slow downloading with Python Script & TOR (Source Code included)

Tags: python, proxy, tor, socks, torsocks

I am trying to Download html pages with my python script & TOR proxy server. It is running well. But extremely slow & Code is not organized so my IP is renewing most of the time rather downloading pages much. How can I speed the downloading with TOR? How can I organize the code efficiency.

Two script is there. Script1 is executed to download html pages from the website & after get block from the website, Script2 has to be executed to renew the IP with help of TOR proxy. So on... IP gets blocked after few seconds.
Should I lower my threading? How ? Please help me to speed up the process. I am getting only 300-500 html pages per hour.

Here is my Full Code of Script1:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import os
import sys
import socks
import socket
import subprocess
import time
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4, '127.0.0.1', 9050, True)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
import urllib2
class WebPage:

    def __init__(self, path, country, url, lower=0,upper=9999):
        self.dir = str(path)+"/"+ str(country)
        self.dir =os.path.join(str(path),str(country))
        self.url = url
        try:
            fin = open(self.dir+"/limit.txt",'r')
            limit = fin.readline()
            limits = str(limit).split(",")
            lower = int(limits[0])
            upper = int(limits[1])
            fin.close()
        except:
            fout = open(self.dir+"/limit.txt",'wb')
            limits = str(lower)+","+str(upper)
            fout.write(limits)
            fout.close()  
        self.process_instances(lower,upper)


    def process_instances(self,lower,upper):
            try:
                os.stat(self.dir)
            except:
                os.mkdir(self.dir)
            for count in range(lower,upper+1):
                if count == upper:
                    print "all downloaded, quitting the app!!"
                    break
                targetURL = self.url+"/"+str(count)
                print "Downloading :" + targetURL
                req = urllib2.Request(targetURL)
                try:
                    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
                    the_page = response.read()  
                    if the_page.find("Your IP suspended")>=0:
                        print "The IP is suspended"
                        fout = open(self.dir+"/limit.txt",'wb')
                        limits = str(count)+","+str(upper)
                        fout.write(limits)
                        fout.close()  
                        break
                    if the_page.find("Too many requests")>=0:
                        print "Too many requests"
                        print "Renew IP...."
                        fout = open(self.dir+"/limit.txt",'wb')
                        limits = str(count)+","+str(upper)
                        fout.write(limits)
                        fout.close()
                        subprocess.Popen("C:\Users\John\Desktop\Data-Mine\yp\lol\lol2.py", shell=True)
                        time.sleep(2)
                        subprocess.call('lol1.py')
                    if the_page.find("404 error")>=0:
                        print "the page not exist"
                        continue
                    self.saveHTML(count, the_page)
                except:
                        print "The URL cannot be fetched"
                        execfile('lol1.py')
                        pass
                        #continue
                        raise                 
    def saveHTML(self,count, content):
        fout = open(self.dir+"/"+str(count)+".html",'wb')
        fout.write(content)
        fout.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len(sys.argv) !=6:
        print "cannot process!!! Five Parameters are required to run the process."
        print "Parameter 1 should be the path where to save the data, eg, /Users/john/data/"
        print "Parameter 2 should be the name of the country for which data is collected, eg, japan"
        print "Parameter 3 should be the URL from which the data to collect, eg, the website link"
        print "Parameter 4 should be the lower limit of the company id, eg, 11 "
        print "Parameter 5 should be the upper limit of the company id, eg, 1000 "
        print "The output will be saved as the HTML file for each company in the target folder's country"
        exit()

       else:
        path = str(sys.argv[1])
        country = str(sys.argv[2])
        url = str(sys.argv[3])
        lowerlimit = int(sys.argv[4])
        upperlimit = int(sys.argv[5])
        WebPage(path, country, url, lowerlimit,upperlimit)
```

Answer (score 0):

TOR is *very* slow, so it is to be expected that you don't get that much pages per hour. There are however some ways to speed it up. Most notably you could turn on GZIP compression for urllib (see [this question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704754/convert-gzipped-data-fetched-by-urllib2-to-html)) to improve the speed a little bit.

TOR as a protocol has rather low bandwidth, because the data needs to be relayed a few times and each relay must use its bandwidth for your request. If data is relayed 6 times - a rather probable number - you would need 6 times the bandwidth. GZIP compression can compress HTML to (in some cases) ~10% of the original size so that will probably speed up the process.

Comment: thank u for the suggestion, but i need to organize the code bit. it looks messy. i m noob to handle it :(